# Bluetooth (BLE) printer - what characteristic to use for print

Tags: printing, bluetooth-lowenergy

Using edge://bluetooth-internal in browser I've successfully connected to BLE printer and sent data to print. I can send data to printer using any characteristic with "Write Without Response" property.
Is this correct way to print for any printer on market or I need to send data to specific characteristic?
If specific characteristic is required how to know which one to use, since I have 3 different characteristic on this printer and I could not find any information online.

Thanks.

Comment: There is no standard for printing over BLE as far as I know. You would probably have to contact the manufacturer and ask for the spec.